# Dynamically add Views in Dialog

Tags: java, android, view, dialog

I am trying to make Dialog that will consist 2x EditText and 1x Buttons. By clicking additional button you can add another 2x EditText and 1x Buttons. This 1x Button provide deleting this added pair. When i try to use button that should add another Views it's working properly. But button for deleting the View is working only for the first pairs. How can i do this with android:onClick, because i was trying buy it crashed.

Here is my code of Dialog class:

```
public class ExampleDialog extends AppCompatDialogFragment {
private EditText editTextUsername;
private EditText editTextPassword;
private ExampleDialogListener listener;
private LinearLayout parentLinearLayout;
private Context mContext;
Button dodaj,usun;



@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_template, null);

    builder.setView(view)
            .setTitle("Login")
            .setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                }
            })
            .setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    String username = editTextUsername.getText().toString();
                    String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();
                    listener.applyTexts(username, password);
                }
            });

    editTextUsername = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_username);
    editTextPassword = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_password);
    parentLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.parent_linear_layout);
    dodaj = view.findViewById(R.id.add_field_button);
    usun = view.findViewById(R.id.delete_button);

    dodaj.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.field, null);
            // Add the new row before the add field button.
            parentLinearLayout.addView(rowView, parentLinearLayout.getChildCount() - 1);
        }
    });

    usun.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            parentLinearLayout.removeView((View) v.getParent());
            usun = v.findViewById(R.id.delete_button);
        }
    });

    return builder.create();
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try {
        listener = (ExampleDialogListener) context;

    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() +
                "must implement ExampleDialogListener");
    }
}

public void contexta(Context context)
{
    this.mContext = context;
}

public interface ExampleDialogListener {
    void applyTexts(String username, String password);
}
```

}

And there is the conception of Dialog box on the picture below:
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ehsys.png)

Answer (score 0):

This issue may be due to view reference. Check whether v.getParent() is the view you want to delete or not.

For testing you can use "removeViewAt(int index)" method. Pass an index and check whether view is deleted at index or not.